# BT on SIM800 not working

Tags: bluetooth, sim800

I cannot get Bluetooth to work on SIM800. AT+GSV command gives following response: SIMCOM_Ltd. 
SIMCOM_SIM800 
Rev: 1308B02SIM800M64_BT. 
Any AT command I type (eg AT_BTSTATUS=?) gives ERROR. What could be the problem?

Comment: Regret the mistake. I tried AT+BTSTATUS? Got ERROR. Tried AT+BTPOWER=1, got ERROR. How do I enable BT? The user guide only gives AT commands and explanation, no troubleshooting guide.

Comment: _Again_, the command is not for example `AT+BTSTATUS?`, but  `AT+BTSTATUS=?`. Here, page 10: http://mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/sim800_series_bluetooth_application_note_v1.04.pdf  **read your documentation**

Comment: Vote to close, as the user failed to read his documentation, resulting in typo-style mistakes. See answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the SIM800 manual here[*], page4, it should be:

```
AT+BTSTATUS?
```

*Not* `AT_BTSTATUS=?`

You may want to have a look at:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Modems_and_AT_Commands#AT_Commands

...and of course read the manual for your module.

*:
http://mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/simcom_sim800_series_bluetooth_application_guide_v1.01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth in SIM800 has to be enabled first in order to be available for use.

To power up the bluetooth radio, just enter:

```
AT+BTPOWER=1
```